# selecting the highest variable in a column per identifier

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I am having a little difficulty with something which I am sure better R users will find very easy. I have a dataframe arranged by identifiers on each row, however some have two rows per identifier. This is because the surveys were asked twice, and I am trying to find the highest of both surveys as a single row.

The rows are structured as - "identifier" followed by "binary variable1", "binary variable2", "binary variable3". The binary can include NA.

minimal reporducible example:

```
cnames <- c("ID", "bin1", "bin2", "bin3")
a<- c("A", 1, 0, 0)
b <- c("A",0, NA, 1)
c <- c("B", 0, 0, 0)
d <- c("B", 0, 1, 0)
aa<- rbind(cnames, a,b,c,d)
aa <- as.data.frame(aa)
```

I would like to create a dataframe with a single row per identifier, with the selection being NA<0<1 so, for instance, ID "A" in the example would become c("A", 1, 0, 1) and "B" would become c("B", 0,1,0).

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3):

You could `summarise` `across` the columns per `group_by` and get the `max` value per column like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
aa %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(bin1:bin3, ~ max(as.numeric(.x), na.rm = TRUE)))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   ID     bin1  bin2  bin3
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A         1     0     1
#> 2 B         0     1     0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data** used:

```
cnames <- c("ID", "bin1", "bin2", "bin3")
a<- c("A", 1, 0, 0)
b <- c("A",0, NA, 1)
c <- c("B", 0, 0, 0)
d <- c("B", 0, 1, 0)
aa<- rbind(cnames, a,b,c,d)
aa <- as.data.frame(aa)
colnames(aa) = aa[1,]
aa = aa[2:5,]
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew this would be something simple, but was struggling!

Answer (score 1):

The solution by Quinten is generally very good.

However, instead of

```
aa %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(bin1:bin3, ~ max(as.numeric(.x), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

I would use the command without as.numeric():

```
aa %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(bin1:bin3, ~ max(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

The reason is that you get unexpected results, when all elements of a column for one identifier are NAs. E.g.:

```
cnames <- c("ID", "bin1", "bin2", "bin3")
a <- c("A", 1, NA, 0)
b <- c("A",0, NA, 1)
c <- c("B", 0, 0, 0)
d <- c("B", 0, 1, 0)
aa<- rbind(a,b,c,d)
aa <- as.data.frame(aa) 
colnames(aa) <- cnames

aa %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(bin1:bin3, ~ max(as.numeric(.x), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

gives you:

```
  ID     bin1  bin2  bin3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1  -Inf     1
2 B         0     1     0
```

The solution without as.numeric gives you the desired result:

```
  ID    bin1  bin2  bin3 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     1     NA    1    
2 B     0     1     0
```

Comment: When using the as.numeric, or without as.numeric, on the whole dataframe I still get the -Inf appearing? It seems to be in subjects with NA in all of the bin1:bin3 if this makes sense